# Application crash when using trace objects

Tags: c#

I'm using the code found at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345134(v=sql.90).aspx but it keeps on crashing when the trace is closed.

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 x64. It fails on Windows 10 x64 and Windows 2012 R2 x64, but works on Windows 7 x86 and Windows 2008 R2 x64.

I'm not changing anything:
The file c:\temp\standard.tdf is obtained by exporting the default template from Profiler. I tried with several template files, still no luck. I tried several versions of SQL Server (2014, 2016, 2017), no joy.

This is the code I'm running:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
//reference: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
// reference c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoExtended.dll
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TraceServer reader = new TraceServer();
            ConnectionInfoBase ci = new SqlConnectionInfo(".\\SQL2014");
            ((SqlConnectionInfo)ci).UseIntegratedSecurity = true;
            reader.InitializeAsReader(ci, @"c:\temp\standard.tdf");
            int eventNumber = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.Write(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                eventNumber++;
                if (eventNumber == 10) break;
            }
            reader.Close();

            // debug reaches the end of the main method, then crashes
        }
    }
}
```

In EventViewer I find this information:

```
Faulting application name: ConsoleApp1.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5a399d47
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.16299.15, time stamp: 0x2cd1ce3d
Exception code: 0xc0020001
Fault offset: 0x001008b2
Faulting process id: 0x59c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3791f189914cd
Faulting application path: c:\users\spagh\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: efe37d30-1589-41fe-82b1-f3248afd7110
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I tried several versions of SMO, to no avail. 
Crashes in debug and in release. Crashes in Windows 10 and Windows 2012 R2.

I'm out of ideas. Any pointers?

Comment: It is an exception that is associated with C++/CLI code.  Occurs when managed code tries to run after the runtime has already shut down.  The only chance you'll have of finding the programmer that wrote that code is through Microsoft Support.  Then again, 14 years is a very long time, he's doing something else today.

Comment: Yes, the code is very old, but the API is still supported. Thanks for the info, at least I know where to look.

Comment: When you build you project are you using the x86 option?  Usually when an call to a method fails on the return it indicates that the return value of the method and the function that calls the method are declaring the size of the return variable differently.  The ax register contains the return value.  So the ax register size can be 16, 32, 64 (the size of an int).  An x86 project will default to a size of 16 while on windows 10 it will be 64 which probably accounts for the crash.

Comment: @jdweng yes, the project is built with x86 and targets framework 3.5. The app.config contains the directives to run on framework 4 (when found) and 3.5.

Comment: Does app run correctly?  May need to register kernalbase.dll.  See : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/kernelbasedll-version-100105860-and-net-runtime/e1b5a9e8-a377-4de7-9a1a-df0bd205a963

Comment: @jdweng Nonsense. There is no such thing as registering kernelbase.

Comment: The app runs correctly, it simply crashes on exit

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're doing? Do you start an trace and then start you project? Or do you start you program and then the trace on the server starts? Did you read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.trace.traceserver.initializeasreader.aspx

Comment: David : Plenty of solutions on web indicating registering works.  Items can get removed from registry.

Comment: @Mötz I am starting the project, which uses the `ConnectionInfo` provided to start a trace on the SQL Server using the template passed as argument. Yes, I did read the documentation for `InitializeAsReader`.

Comment: @jdweng Utter nonsense. There is nowhere in the system where kernelbase.dll needs to be registered. Perhaps you could entertain us all by telling me which registry key is used to register this system DLL.

Comment: @jdweng As for your comment on the AX register, that is also nonsense. The AX register is 16 bits wide. It's the low 16 bits of the 32 bit EAX register. That in turn is the low 32 bits of the 64 bit RAX register on a 64 bit system. On both x86 and x64 architectures though, an `int` is 32 bits wide. That entire comment on return values was 100% bogus.

Comment: David : We will never agree.I din't get into the details of the diff between ax, eax, and rax.But I debugged lots of mixed language programs and found cases where app ran and failed on the returns.These issue where always due to the size of the return variable being wrong.The compiler store the return location on the stack followed by the ax register followed by the parameter list.  When sizes of the params are wrong the app doesn't run.  On the return the ax register is pop off of stack and put into ax register.  Then the program counter is restored.  When ax is wrong PC get load incorrectly.

Comment: @jdweng No, you are talking utter nonsense here. For an `int` return value, no address is placed on the stack. The callee places the return value into the EAX register, and the caller reads it when the function returns. And let's be clear, `int` is 32 bits wide on both x86 and x64. Or do you disagree with that also? I'm also still hoping that you can provide that entertainment with the registry keys, but I am ready to be disappointed.

Comment: I said what the compiler does.  You are referring to assembly language coding.

Comment: Guys, I appreciate your help, but I think you should get a room if you want to continue arguing like that.

Comment: @jdweng Nope. I'm referring to calling conventions, just as you are.

Comment: Try adding `GC.KeepAlive(reader);` at the very end of your method. Also, does it need to be disposed? If you're not disposing it likely it is handled by the finalizer thread, which (that is, the dispose method of this object) may not work after the program has started shutting down.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thank you for the suggestion. I tried `GC.KeepAlive` and didn't work. Same outcome with `Dispose`

Answer (score 5):

I was able to reproduce the issue on my own lab machine.

I did a lot of searching on google for the reported exception code: 0x0020001. The exception is normally something with managed code loading unmanaged code, where the unmanaged code "hangs" and tries to "report" back into the managed code - but the managed code did exit and therefor it fails.

[Link 1](http://faithlife.codes/blog/2008/04/exception_0xc0020001_in_ccli_assembly/)

[Link 2](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/5-tips-for-understanding-managed-unmanaged-interoperability-in-net/)

I did spend some time on reverse engineer the dll files with ILSpy to see where things end up.

Looking at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.TraceServer.InitializeAsReader()
we see this:

```
// Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.TraceServer
public void InitializeAsReader(ConnectionInfoBase serverConnInfo, string profileFileName)
{
    try
    {
        this.rowsetCtrl = (TraceUtils.CreateInstance("\\Binn\\pfclnt.dll", "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.CTraceObjectsRowsetController") as ITraceObjectsRowsetController);
        this.rowsetCtrl.Initialize(serverConnInfo, profileFileName);
        this.rowsetCtrl.InitSource(false);
        this.traceController = this.rowsetCtrl;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TraceUtils.FilterException(ex);
        throw new SqlTraceException(typeof(StringConnectionInfo), "CannotInitializeAsReader", ex);
    }
}
```

The line we need to focus on first is:

```
this.rowsetCtrl = (TraceUtils.CreateInstance("\\Binn\\pfclnt.dll", "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.CTraceObjectsRowsetController") as ITraceObjectsRowsetController);
```

It just a way to load the:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\PFCLNT.DLL
file into memory

If we look into the PFCLNT.DLL file, and looking for the Initialize and InitSource methods, they are not standard C# methods:

```
// Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.CTraceObjectsRowsetController
public unsafe void Initialize(ConnectionInfoBase pConnInfo, string pTemplateFileName)
{
    ITraceConnection* ptr = <Module>.CreateOleDbTraceConnection();
    if (null == ptr)
    {
        <Module>.?A0xa0507c21.ProcessError(-2147024882, null);
    }
    CTraceControllerBase.ConvertConnectionInfoToITraceConnection(pConnInfo, ptr);
    ITraceConnection* expr_1D = ptr;
    int num = calli(System.Int32 modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong) modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvThiscall)(System.IntPtr), expr_1D, *(*(int*)expr_1D + 12));
    if (num < 0)
    {
        $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G = 0;
        initblk(ref $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G + 2, 0, 1022);
        object arg_50_0 = calli(System.Int32 modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong) modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvThiscall)(System.IntPtr,System.UInt16*), ptr, ref $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G, *(*(int*)ptr + 180));
        <Module>.?A0xa0507c21.ProcessError(num, (ushort*)(&$ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G));
    }
    byte b = 0;
    byte b2 = 0;
    int num2 = calli(System.Int32 modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong) modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvThiscall)(System.IntPtr,System.Byte*,System.Byte*,System.UInt16*), ptr, ref b, ref b2, 0, *(*(int*)ptr + 148));
    if (num2 < 0)
    {
        $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G2 = 0;
        initblk(ref $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G2 + 2, 0, 1022);
        object arg_9A_0 = calli(System.Int32 modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong) modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvThiscall)(System.IntPtr,System.UInt16*), ptr, ref $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G2, *(*(int*)ptr + 180));
        <Module>.?A0xa0507c21.ProcessError(num2, (ushort*)(&$ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G2));
    }
    if (b < 9)
    {
        ITraceConnection* ptr2 = null;
        int num3 = calli(System.Int32 modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong) modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvThiscall)(System.IntPtr,ITraceConnection/eConnectionType,ITraceConnection**), ptr, 0, ref ptr2, *(*(int*)ptr + 28));
        if (num3 < 0)
        {
            $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G3 = 0;
            initblk(ref $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G3 + 2, 0, 1022);
            object arg_E6_0 = calli(System.Int32 modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong) modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvThiscall)(System.IntPtr,System.UInt16*), ptr, ref $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G3, *(*(int*)ptr + 180));
            <Module>.?A0xa0507c21.ProcessError(num3, (ushort*)(&$ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G3));
        }
        ITraceConnection* expr_F1 = ptr;
        object arg_FB_0 = calli(System.UInt32 modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong) modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall)(System.IntPtr), expr_F1, *(*(int*)expr_F1 + 8));
        ptr = ptr2;
        ITraceConnection* expr_101 = ptr2;
        num2 = calli(System.Int32 modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong) modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvThiscall)(System.IntPtr), expr_101, *(*(int*)expr_101 + 12));
        if (num2 < 0)
        {
            $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G4 = 0;
            initblk(ref $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G4 + 2, 0, 1022);
            object arg_132_0 = calli(System.Int32 modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong) modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvThiscall)(System.IntPtr,System.UInt16*), ptr, ref $ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G4, *(*(int*)ptr + 180));
            <Module>.?A0xa0507c21.ProcessError(num2, (ushort*)(&$ArrayType$$$BY0CAA@G4));
        }
    }
    this.templateFileName = pTemplateFileName;
    byte* ptr3 = pTemplateFileName;
    if (ptr3 != null)
    {
        ptr3 = RuntimeHelpers.OffsetToStringData + ptr3;
    }
    Char modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsConst)& char modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsConst)& = ptr3;
    CTraceRowsetCtrl* ptr4 = <Module>.@new(16460u);
    CTraceRowsetCtrl* ptr5;
    try
    {
        if (ptr4 != null)
        {
            ptr5 = <Module>.CTraceRowsetCtrl.{ctor}(ptr4, ptr, char modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsConst)&);
        }
        else
        {
            ptr5 = 0;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        <Module>.delete((void*)ptr4);
        throw;
    }
    this.m_pTraceCtrl = ptr5;
    if (0 == ptr5)
    {
        <Module>.?A0xa0507c21.ProcessError(-2147024882, null);
    }
    ITraceConnection* expr_192 = ptr;
    object arg_19C_0 = calli(System.UInt32 modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong) modopt(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall)(System.IntPtr), expr_192, *(*(int*)expr_192 + 8));
}
```

So with my very limited knowledge about this, I would argue that you're facing something that is out of your hands. I believe that we need to catch someone at microsoft, leveraging your network and the SQL community, to have them look into why it fails.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the effort you put into your answer. I highly appreciate it.